# Regex for fixed length string, starting with multiple words with different length

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that matches a string that is **exactly 10 characters** in length and must start with either "ESZ", "XXZ", "H" or "A2/10". 
I tried something like this but I can't specify the total string's length because of the length variation in the starting words:

```
      ^(ESZ|XXZ|H|A2/10).{5,9}$
```

How to specify the total string's length to '10' in this case?

Comment: ^(?=\w{10}$)(ESZ|XXZ|H|A2/10).*

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Is your regex flvour supporting lookahead?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ test site. all options by default

Comment: PCRE (PHP) by default on the web site

Answer (score 2):

Since the alternatives are so few, why not specify them all with `^(ESZ.{7}|XXZ.{7}|H.{9}|A2\/10.{5})$`?

https://regex101.com/r/5BwTWP/1

*EDIT:*

This can alternatively be achieved by : `(?=.{10}$)(ESZ|XXZ|H1|A2\/10)`

https://regex101.com/r/5BwTWP/3

This regex first does a lookahead to make sure there are 10 chars in the string. Something like a check for `string.length === 10` before regex matching should also do.

I still think the very first approach is the simplest and most efficient.

Comment: yes, as an option. thanks. Can the whole length be set for a string to be more elegant?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by elegant. If it is purely about efficiency, then first checking the length and then matching will add an extra step. If you strictly want to have a very short regex, another option is to first length check the string and then just `ESZ|XXZ|H...`

Comment: how I can do 'first length check the string'?

Comment: thanks! if I add ^$ - does not work. Without these ^$ - match only 'ESZ'..

Comment: You need to add: '.*' at the end, that is a dot and a star (so it ends up being like my comment :)

Comment: @gmlvsv  You can add `^` to the very beginning of the regex to match the start of the pattern. As for not returning the full string after the match was found, that's how lookaheads work. A remedy would be doing what @Poul Bak is suggesting. But I would be curious why length check is so important that you cannot do it outside of regex? If you explain that, maybe we could help you better.

Comment: @gmlvsv Keep in mind that a lookahead will have to traverse 10 chars and then go back, while simple patterns in this answer do not need any length check.

Comment: I am using regex in SQLs and I do not know the length outside the regex to check it